# Python Mock - check if method was called from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-mock

How can I check if method is called inside another method, when those methods are from different classes?

If they are from same class, I can do this:

```
from unittest import mock

class A():
  def method_a(self):
    pass

  def method_b(self):
    self.method_a()

a = A()
a.method_a = mock.MagicMock()
a.method_b()
a.method_a.assert_called_once_with()
```

But if `method_a` would be from different class, then it would raise `AssertionError` that it was not called.

How could I do same check if I would have these classes instead (and I want to check if `method_b` calls `method_a`)?:

```
class A():
  def method_a(self):
    pass

class B():
  def method_b(self):
    A().method_a()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply stub `A` within the same context as `B`, and validate against the way it would have been called.  Example:

```
>>> class B():
...   def method_b(self):
...     A().method_a()
... 
>>> A = mock.MagicMock()
>>> A().method_a.called
False
>>> b = B()
>>> b.method_b()
>>> A().method_a.called
True
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really straightforward.